# Central backup with windows server 2012 standard

Tags: windows-backup, windows-server-2012

Today i read an article about backing up clients on a windows 2012 essential server,
declaring this as an essential exclusive feature. Can anyone describe me how to backup clients on a windows 2012 std server?

Or maybe just posting a link about this topic ?

Comment: How about a link to the article. Its not clear what your question is exactly.  The feature set of windows 2012 essential server is well documented on Microsoft's website.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in saying that this is an Essentials only feature. If you can install another server, Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard has a new server role called "Essentials Experience". This will work as Standard, with Essentials features installed too. If you cannot do this, then you need to setup backups on each client computer to a network location as normal.